# How can you train a word2vec in gensim from a list of co-occurrence (bigram) counts?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I am trying to train a word2vec model with the [COHA corpus](http://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) by using pre-computed bigram counts co-occurrence counts that the corpus' author makes available [here](https://www.ngrams.info/download_coha.asp).

How can I achieve that using [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Gensim's `Word2Vec` class expects its training corpus to be an iterable of actual texts (lists of word-tokens). The innermost training loops, where the skip-gram algorithm works on pairs of within-context-window words, aren't factored to allow you to supply more raw corpus variants.

Since it looks like that corpus is (or soon will be) available as full texts, I'd recommend obtaining & using it in that form. Then, you could tinker with different `window` values.

If you absolutely need to work with the 2-grams, those do closely mimic what a skip-gram training with a `window=1`, so you could try creating a synthetic corpus from that data.

That is, for every bigram with a count of occurrences, create that many 2-word texts. (For example, if the data includes `(('fat', 'cat'), 3)` – meaning the bigram `"fat cat"` appeared 3 times in the real texts, create the pseudotexts `[['fat', 'cat'], ['fat', 'cat'], ['fat', 'cat']]`.) Then, concatenate & shuffly all these 2-word texts together – so that identical or similar bigrams don't appear in runs/clumps. (Interleaved contrasting examples are better for model training than long runs of identical/alike texts.)

Then use *that* synthetic set of texts to train `Word2Vec`. You should get word-vectors very similar, in utility, to what you'd get on the real texts, with `window=1, sg=1`.